# Drunk Passenger Probability question

Tags: probability, word-problem

I don't know how to solve this question. A line of 100 airline passengers are waiting to board a plane. They each hold a ticket to one of the 100 seats on the flight. For convenience, lets say that the n-th passenger in line has a ticket for the seat number n. Being drunk, the first person in line picks a random set (equally likely for each seat). All of the other passengers are sober, and will go to their proper seats unless it is already occupied; In this case, they will randomly choose a free seat. You're person number 100. What is the probability you end up in your seat (seat #100)?

Comment: @jojo-Is the random seat selected by the drunk man seat your 100th sit by any chance?Then the probability is clearly zero...

Answer (score 0):

I am simplifying the problem for you.Let there be 8 seats and yours is the 8th seat.Let the 7th seat is occupied by drunk man but his predefined seat is number 1.All other people up to number till 6 occupies their own seats.Now it depends on number 7 if he will occupy seat number 1 or your 8th seat.So you have a probability of getting your predefined seat as-$$p(a)=\frac12$$

Here p(a) denotes the probability of getting your proper seat.

Comment: Though your answer is correct, need a little more explanation or convincing about your assumptions